# Formatar segundos para minutos e segundos (MM:SS) no PERL

Tags: datetime, data, conversão, perl

Eu tenho um valor inteiro de segundos e estou tentando converter apenas minutos e segundos, ou seja, somando os minutos caso passe de 60.

Resumindo:

> Se eu tenho o valor 125 em segundos, deve retornar 02:05
>
> Se eu tenho o valor 7200 em segundos, deve retornar 120:00

O que eu tentei fazer foi o seguinte:

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

strftime('%M:%S', gmtime $seconds);
```

Porém o retorno não é esperado, ele pega somente o minuto e o segundo e não faz o calculo como deveria.

Ficando assim:

> Se eu tenho o valor 125 em segundos, ele retorna corretamente 02:05
>
> Se eu tenho o valor 7200 em segundos, ele retorna 00:00 e não como
> deveria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes precisamos entender dois conceitos importantes: horários e durações. Considere as frases abaixo:

- A reunião foi às duas horas da tarde
- O filme tem duas horas de duração

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" é um horário: um momento específico do dia.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" é uma duração: uma quantidade de tempo, não necessariamente relacionada a um horário específico (não é dito que horas começa ou termina, nem sequer é dito se ele de fato foi assistido).

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, segundos) e até mesmo a forma de exibição pode ser a mesma (um relógio mostra "02:00" quando são 2 horas, um cronômetro mostra "02:00" quando já se passaram 2 horas). Mas eles são conceitos diferentes.

---

Dito isso, `strftime` serve para trabalhar com datas/horas, mas não com durações.

Uma forma de resolver é fazer os cálculos manualmente. Como você tem uma duração em segundos e quer quebrá-la em horas e segundos, bastaria fazer isso:

```perl
$total_seconds = 7200;
$hours = $total_seconds / 60;
$seconds = $total_seconds % 60;
printf "%02d:%02d\n", $hours, $seconds; # 120:00
```

Ou, se quer guardar o valor formatado em uma variável:

```perl
$total_seconds = 7200;
$hours = $total_seconds / 60;
$seconds = $total_seconds % 60;

# a variável $formatado terá como valor a string "120:00"
$formatado = sprintf "%02d:%02d", $hours, $seconds;
```

---

Obs: para trabalhar com durações também existem os módulos [`DateTime::Duration`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration) e [`DateTime::Format::Duration`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration). Antes certifique-se que os módulos estão instalados, usando o `cpan`:

```
cpan DateTime::Duration
cpan DateTime::Format::Duration
```

Estes comandos verificam se os módulos estão instalados, e caso não esteja, já faz a instalação automaticamente.

Depois bastaria usá-los para criar a duração e formatá-la. **O problema é que eles não conseguem tratar o caso em que a quantidade de minutos é maior que 60**:

```perl
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

sub formatar {
    my ($seconds) = @_;
    my $duration = DateTime::Duration->new(seconds => $seconds);
    my $df = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(pattern => '%M:%S', normalize => 1);
    print $df->format_duration($duration);
}

# ok
formatar(125); # 02:05

# não ok
formatar(7200); # 00:00
```

Isso ocorre porque a normalização faz com que 7200 segundos se transforme em 2 horas, zero minutos e zero segundos (já sem a normalização nenhum dos casos funciona, pois ele mantém o valor dos segundos como está). Então a única opção para ter o resultado que você quer é fazer as contas manualmente mesmo.